# Difficulties making a website design responsive

Tags: html, css, frontend, responsive

I want to make my design more responsive. But whenever I make those background circles, it stops being responsive, and the image of the person and the yellow circle stop sticking to the center. Any tips on how I can do it better and more efficiently?

I'm having difficulties making it responsive cause all the elements have `position: absolute`. I am currently doing it like this:

```
<div className="background">
   <div className='outer-circle'></div>     // Gray circles
   <img src={landingPersonImage} alt="">    // Image of the person
   <div className='section1-img-bg'></div>  // Yellow circle
</div>
```

[image: Sample design]

My main issue is that the yellow circle is not sticking to the center of those background circles. Here is a video of what I mean:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZA_skdNAyt2L9pewoTIuIF4CKJLCsqIR/view?usp=share_link

Codepen - https://codepen.io/c0mpli-the-scripter/pen/OJExaLR
Grey is replaced with green for better visibilty.

Comment: Try to refrain from using position absolute as much as possible, and whenever you truely need to use it put it in a wrapper container that has `position relative` so it will contain the items, then using the position relative container you will be able to position it to your liking on responsive views.

Comment: Writing code which automatically adjusts itself for any given width and height of device.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `background` element a [grid container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) and its children - [named grid areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas). This way you can position them whatever you want depending on the `@media` query.
Also don't forget to wrap the `<img>` element in `<span>`/`<div>`, since the behaviour of replaced elements as flex/grid items is inconsistent between browsers.

Comment: okay but how can i make it change on z index. Cause there are 3 elements, grey circles, person img, yellow circle. The person img sits on top of yellow circle which sits on top of grey circles?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="/"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the CSS code

```
.parent{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.parent .wrapper{
 min-width: 250px; // just for example
 //or use flex-basis
 flex-basis: 250px;
}

.parent .text{
 min-width: 350px; // just for example
 //or use flex-basis
 flex-basis: 350px;
}
```

Now you controlled these 2 divs and they will fit your screen and wrap when you get to their min-width.

Comment: When i try to put the img inside the circle, ill have to use position absolute right?
```
<div className="wrapper> //yellow circle
<img/>//person img 
<div>
```
Is this what you are trying to say right?

Comment: Yes, it's better to control this photo and you can hide its bottom also and handle both of them as one.

Comment: ive added a video to my problem(output), could you please check it out and let me know a better approach?

Comment: You can share your code on codepen for example to be able to help you.

Comment: I can't open videos right now but I can edit your code if you share it.

Comment: If you're using display: flex then add align-items: center and justify-content: center it will fix it.
I've seen your video.

Comment: okay wait ill add a codepen